# how to merge multiple row into single one considering the label

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with every row containing one sentence.

I want to merge the rows in together, so that every row contains 4 sentences of every author.

I have something like this data frame:

```
text:           author
sent1             x
sent2             x   
sent3             x  
..
sent1002          x 
sent1             y
sent2             y
sent3             y
..
sent2598          y
sent1             z
sent2             z
sent3             z
..
sent3698          z
```

and I want to convert it into something like this:

```
text                                 author
setn1,sent2,sent3,sent4                 x
..
sent1000,sent1001,sent1002,sent1003     y
sent1,sent2,sent3,sent4                 z
```

Comment: Hi mary, please provide a piece of code we can run to generate an example of your input, and a piece of code to generate your desired output for that input.

Comment: @ibarrond thanks for your answer...
print df.groupby('author')['text'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
i wrote sth like this... but it join all the sent in together... i just want to make chunk with 4 sentence  for each row, not all sentence of one author...

Comment: there are several ways to do this. one easy way is first "sort" the list based on the second column. so, the data with the same author are below each other. the use a for loop: for i in range (0,len(df)):  if df[i,1]==df[i+1,1]: add the first columns to gether. and then remove the i+1 row.   hope it helps

Comment: Whats the logic behind this operation ?

Comment: i want to get some stylometry feature from text and i can not get a good result from one sentence in a sample, the sugestion was to convert each sample into multi sentence chunks @Manakin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#sample data
print (df)
        text author
0      sent1      x
1      sent2      x
2      sent3      x
3   sent1002      x
4      sent1      x
5      sent2      x
6      sent3      x
7   sent2598      y
8      sent1      y
9      sent2      y
10     sent3      y
11  sent3698      y
```

Because need aggregate by each 4 sentences use counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and pass to another `groupby` with `join`:

```
g = df.groupby('author').cumcount() // 4

df1 = (df.groupby(['author', g])['text']
        .agg(','.join)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='text4'))
print (df1)
  author                       text4
0      x  sent1,sent2,sent3,sent1002
1      x           sent1,sent2,sent3
2      y  sent2598,sent1,sent2,sent3
3      y                    sent3698
```