# How to perform windowed operation on dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Given

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ssss = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6))
```

`ssss`:

```
   0
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
```

I want to perform a sliding window operation on the dataframe.

I want to perform a *general* function (in this case mean, but it can be another function and involve more than one input column), on a sliding window of arbitrary size, with arbitrary strides.

In this case, the window size is 2, and the stride length is also 2.

Does pandas support this kind of operation?

res:

```
   0 res
0  0 0.5
1  1 0.5
2  2 2.5
3  3 2.5
4  4 4.5
5  5 4.5
```

---

It seems like `groupby` is not what I am looking for.

I could go to a numpy solution, but even then I am not sure what's the standard approach. I would expect pandas to support something like this, but couldn't find any method that does that.

---

Edit:

`ssss`:

Assume column 1 values are strings

```
   0 1   2
0  0 "5" a
1  1 "4" b
2  2 "3" c
3  3 "2" d
4  4 "1" e
5  5 "0" f
```

I would like to use as a very general example

```
def row_reduce(col0, col1):
    return str(2 * col0) + col1

def col_reduce(rows_data):
    return ",".join(rows_data)
```

to obtain (while ignoring column 2)

```
   0 1   2 res
0  0 "5" a "05,24"
1  1 "4" b "05,24"
2  2 "3" c "43,62"
3  3 "2" d "43,62"
4  4 "1" e "81,100"
5  5 "0" f "81,100"
```

This first performs the row reduction using the custom function, then performs a windowed column reduction.

Comment: There is [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) but to my great disappointment the step size is still hardcoded to 1.

Comment: @timgeb I actually thought about this, and wondered what would be the expected output if step size were not 1. I figured it wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If windows are not overlapped you can use `groupby`.

I think you need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with integer division:

```
#if default RangeIndex
ssss['res'] = ssss.groupby(ssss.index // 2)[0].transform('mean')
#any index - helper array
ssss['res'] = ssss.groupby(np.arange(len(ssss)) // 2)[0].transform('mean')
print (ssss)
   0  res
0  0  0.5
1  1  0.5
2  2  2.5
3  3  2.5
4  4  4.5
5  5  4.5
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  0  5  a
1  1  4  b
2  2  3  c
3  3  2  d
4  4  1  e
5  5  0  f

def row_reduce(col0, col1):
    return str(2 * col0) + str(col1)

def col_reduce(rows_data):
    return ",".join(rows_data)


df['res'] = (df.apply(lambda x: row_reduce(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
               .groupby(df.index // 2)
               .transform(col_reduce))
print (df)
   0  1  2     res
0  0  5  a   05,24
1  1  4  b   05,24
2  2  3  c   43,62
3  3  2  d   43,62
4  4  1  e  81,100
5  5  0  f  81,100
```

Comment: How would I use a function of my own, that can take more columns as input?

Comment: Please see edit. I tried to be as general and precise as possible.

Comment: maybe the `",".join` makes less sense, but I hope this communicates the main idea

Comment: Also, please notice ssss.index // 2 does not allow for strides to overlap, but if this is for another question I wouldn't mind.

Comment: In the most general case windows can overlap. But let's keep it simple for now?

Comment: @Gulzar - hmmm, in my opinion there are 2 different things, if need strides with sliding window? Or not overlapping groups likehere.

Comment: @Gulzar - But if need processing some sliding windows, so here e.g. `0,1,2` , `1,2,3`, `2,3,4`, ... then `groupby` cannot be used, need sliders - in pandas `rolling` or numpy strides, e.g. some my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2901002+strides) using same function.

Comment: let's forget overlapping windows for now.

Comment: @Gulzar - Super, it is more simple;)

Comment: Thanks! What if my index is a multi-index? I need to perform exactly this operation, but on each row of the 0'th level of the multi index individually, meaning grouping, windowing and so on by the 1st level, for each row of the 0ths level. Should I use .apply on that level, or is there something smarter?

Comment: @Gulzar - I think you can use this grouping trick like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64552942/2901002) with change `g = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() // 2` and then `df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0), g])`

Comment: Thanks, I actually don't understand. Why use cumcount, and why use `//2`? We already have the `level=0` as unique groups. Should I start a new question for this?

Comment: @Gulzar - Not sure if understand, so maybe new question will be fine, I will be offline, so someone else answer for you.

Comment: follow up for multi index is here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64577695/how-to-perform-complicated-df-action-for-all-rows-of-multi-level-index-dataframe

Comment: Also, once I do this, I am left with a lot of duplicated values. Is there a smart way to avoid the duplication, but still remain in a single dataframe table, rather than holding another one `on the side` and keep playing with references?