# How to perform complicated df action for all rows of multi level index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up question [for this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64553902/how-to-perform-windowed-operation-on-dataframe) - for the case where input dataframe has a multi-index, rather than a regular index.

I would like to perform some complicated operation `foo` that takes in a single-index-df and perform it on all the dfs that are the rows that are obtained by looking at level 0 of the 2-level-index, row by row.

take the same input from the linked question augmented to also have a multi index.

```
i0 i1   0 1   2 
0  0    0 "5" a 
   1    1 "4" b
1  2    2 "3" c
   3    3 "2" d 
   4    4 "1" e 
   5    5 "0" f
```

So I would like to perform `foo` on

```
i1     0 1   2
 0      0 "5" a
 1      1 "4" b
```

and on

```
i1     0 1   2
 2     2 "3" c
 3     3 "2" d
 4     4 "1" e
 5     5 "0" f
```

to obtain another dataframe, whose columns depend on what `foo` returns.

For the a function `foo` like the one in the referenced question,

`foo` would return

```
i0 i1 res
0  0  "05,24"
   1  "05,24"
1  2  "43,62"
   3  "43,62"
   4  "81,100"
   5  "81,100"
```

---

My attempt:

```
def row_reduce(col0, col1):
    return str(2 * col0) + str(col1)

def col_reduce(rows_data):
    return ",".join(rows_data)

def foo(df):
    res = (df.apply(lambda x: row_reduce(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
                   .groupby(df.index // 2)
                   .transform(col_reduce))
    return res


def _perform_operation_on_all_main_ind(df: pd.DataFrame, op: Callable[[pd.DataFrame], pd.DataFrame]):
    return df.groupby(level=0).apply(op)

_perform_operation_on_all_main_ind(df, foo)
```

Which then gives me `TypeError: cannot perform __floordiv__ with this index type: MultiIndex`, meaning the multi index didn't get reduced to a single index.

Maybe I have it backwards and you can show me the correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `foo` function for integer division by helper array by length of `DataFrame`, last add `group_keys=False` for avoid duplcicated first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
def foo(df):
    res = (df.apply(lambda x: row_reduce(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
                   .groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2)
                   .transform(col_reduce))
    return res


df = df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(foo)
print (df)
i0  i1
0   0      05,24
    1      05,24
1   2      43,62
    3      43,62
    4     81,100
    5     81,100
dtype: object
```