# How to perform a sliding window operation on a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the same as [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64553902/how-to-perform-windowed-operation-on-dataframe), but this time the windows can overlap.

I want to control the window size, [and what happens at the edges (although for now "same" padding will do)].

input:

```
a
0
5
2
1
8
2
5
```

`window_size=3`, `op=np.max`

result:

```
a res
0 5
5 5
2 5
1 8
8 8
2 8
5 5
```

---

I would also like to pass generic functions, both to reduce columns and to reduce rows, as seen in the linked question.

---

Bonus:

If i don't need to calculate all values, I could do a strided running window with stride > 1, and fill in nans in the rest. Can this be done to save calculations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want something like this

```
df['res'] = df['a'].rolling(3, min_periods=0, center=True).max()
```

For generic functions, you should replace `.max()` with `.aggregate(fn)`

Comment: Thanks! this works for a single index df, but when doing this on a df with a multi index, i get the 2nd level duplicated. `df[["a"]].groupby(level=0).drop.rolling(window=500, min_periods=0).aggregate(np.mean)` returns a 3-level index on a 2-level index input

Comment: of course this wasn't the exact question, but maybe you have a quick fix?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but it might be an effect of the groupby. You could drop the index afterwards maybe. On a normal Multi index dataframe, it works as expected